# MonoTouch: Flurry Analytics

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, flurry

Using the new http://Xamarin.com wrapped assembly for Flurry (thank you Xamarin) I am porting my apps that used the old binding to the new one.

Where do I set the Flurry API Key for the app?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The API key is set in the FinishedLaunching method in the AppDelegate, and should be called *before* any of the rest of the delegate code:

```
public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
{
    FlurryAnalytics.StartSession("YOUR_API_KEY");

    //
    //your code goes here...
    //
}
```

Check out the sample for some decent coverage of the API usage:
https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/FlurryAnalytics/sample